# Org-src-fontify-natively makes Magit think there are unsaved files

Tags: org-mode, magit

I've got a weird one for you. When all of the following are true:

- I'm using org-mode
- My org-mode file has a code block
- I export the org file
- `org-src-fontify-natively` is true

Then I get a leftover buffer with a name like " org-src-fontification:clojure-mode". It's considered an "invisible" buffer, so it only shows up when listing buffers from Elisp code. It does not appear in the interactive buffer list.

The next time I refresh my magit-status, I get prompted to save a file. There's no option to skip it! If I save the file, it has the contents of the leftover internal buffer.

If I turn off `org-src-fontify-natively` then this doesn't happen. But my exports also don't get nice fontification either.

Is there some way to either discard that buffer, or convince magit to ignore it?

Comment: Does `C-x s` instead of `magit-status` cause the same prompt?

Comment: @npostavs Yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to advise the functions involved. For example, you could add `:after` advice to `org-src-font-lock-fontify-block` to kill the buffer it creates, perhaps like this:

```
(defun kill-org-src-buffers (&rest args)
  "Kill temporary buffers created by
org-src-font-lock-fontify-block so they don't interfere with
magit-mode."
  (dolist (b (buffer-list))
    (let ((bufname (buffer-name b)))
      (if (string-prefix-p " org-src-fontification:" bufname)
          (kill-buffer b)))))

(advice-add 'org-src-font-lock-fontify-block
            :after #'kill-org-src-buffers)
```

The `kill-org-src-buffers` iterates over all buffers, killing any that match the buffer name prefix that `org-src-font-lock-fontify-block` uses for its "temporary" buffers. Alternatively, advising `magit-save-repository-buffers` with `:before` advice that takes a similar approach would likely work too.

I think it's a bug that `org-src-font-lock-fontify-block` creates a buffer using `get-buffer-create` to do work that appears to require only a temporary buffer; it should use `with-temp-buffer` instead.

Comment: I think the actual bug is that the "temporary" buffer ends up visiting a file (I guess they're purposely reusing the buffer for efficiency).

Comment: Would you consider filing a bug? It sounds like the solution wouldn't be too challenging.

Comment: @PythonNut: normally, yes, I'd submit a patch, especially when the solution is as easy as what's required here: a 3-line change to use `with-temp-buffer` instead of `with-current-buffer` and `get-buffer-create`. But in this case, I'm not an actual user of either `org-mode` or `magit-mode`. To report an `org-mode` bug it appears I'd have to sign up to their mailing list, learn their requirements for how to format the bug report just so they'd even consider it, and actually run `org-mode` and `magit-mode` to get the details needed for the report.